# Contract via proxy missing functions

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts

I thought that proxy simply uses delegate call to the implementation contract. So the way I see this, is that I can run the same method in proxy and in implementation. However, I did deploy my ERC20 contract via proxy and found out, that I can't mint directly on the implementation contract, only through proxy. How? Why? I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to call the implementation functions interacting directly with the implementation contract, your functions will be run in a different context reading/writing to the storage of the implementation contract instead of the proxy contract. Not generally what you want. Kind of split brain.